# Find $a$ such that the existence and uniqueness theorem applies to the ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I want to find all the real constants $a$ such that the existence and uniqueness theorem applies to the ivp $x'=\frac{3}{2}|x|^\frac{1}{3}, x(0)=a$.

My approach is finding for which constants $a$ the function $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}|x|^\frac{1}{3}$ is lipschitzian at $x=a$. Is this a correct approach? If yes, could you help me showing which $a$ $f(x)$ is atleast locally lipschitzian?

edit:
$f(x)$ is continuously differentiable wrt $x$ for all $x\neq0$ and there exists a ngbh at those points where it's derivative is bounded, implying $f(x)$ being lipschitzian at all points $x \neq 0$. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you say is correct. For all $x \neq 0$, $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $x$, hence locally Lipschitz continuous in such a neighborhood of $x$. The hypothesis of [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) are fulfilled and you can state the existence and uniqueness of the solution to the IVP:
$$x'=\frac{3}{2}|x|^\frac{1}{3}, x(0)=a.$$

**It remains to study the case $a=0$**. As [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) only involves a material implication (and not an equivalence), you CANNOT state that (at least) a solution doesn't exist or is not unique directly.

However,$f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and you can invoke [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) to state that a solution exists. But uniqueness is not guaranteed.

**A trivial solution is the always vanishing map**. If you try to solve directly the ODE by separating the variables, you'll find an infinity of other solutions. Namely

$$x(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{for } t \le c\\
(t-c)^{3/2} & \text{for } t \ge c
\end{cases}$$

For all $c >0$ are also solutions. I let you discover what happens using $c < 0$.

Comment: You mean, in the first sentence,  for all $x\neq 0$ right? Otherwise im confused. I understsnd everything after that

Comment: @Sam Yes. Thanks for noting the typo!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. It generates the answer $a>0$.

If $a>0$, then the unique solution of the ivp is
$$x(t)=(a^{2/3}+t)^{3/2}.$$
Note that $x(t)>0$ holds for all $t$ such that the function $f$ is Lipschitz (in fact differentiable) at $x(t)$ for all $t$.

If $a=0$, then there are at least two solutions, namely $x_1(t)=0$ for all $t$ and $x_2(t)=t^{3/2}$ for all $t$.

Finally, if $a<0$, then there exist also at least two solutions, namely
$$x_1(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}-(|a|^{2/3}-t)^{3/2}&\mbox{ if }t\leq |a|^{2/3}\\
0&\mbox{ if }t>|a|^{2/3},\end{array}\right.$$
and 
$$x_2(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}-(|a|^{2/3}-t)^{3/2}&\mbox{ if }t\leq |a|^{2/3}\\
(t-|a|^{2/3})^{3/2}&\mbox{ if }t>|a|^{2/3},\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: You are right that $f$ is Lipschitz for $x<0$. However, if $a<0$, then the trajectory that starts in $a$ reaches 0 in finite time and from that point onwards there exist multiple continuations as illustrated in my answer.

Comment: OK. I understand the issue... which is not so easy to formulate. For $a \neq 0$, the existence and uniqueness theorem applies. So the solutions are locally unique. And the OP title is indeed about applying the theorem. However, if you look at larger intervals, the solutions might not be unique anymore when those reach points where $x=0$. Even for $a>0$, global solutions are not unique. Look at what happen for $t=-a^{2/3}$: you can extend the solution to the left with the always vanishing map. Hope it is clear enough...